# How to add JSplitPane between the JTabbedPane and its components?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, java-6, jsplitpane

This is my code given below as:

```
theJTabbedPane.addTab(CODING, new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/sysvine/healthpractice/gui/images/tablet.png")), aPanelDiagIcd);//Constant.getTextBundle("5.การวินิจฉัย")
    aPanelDiagIcd.addPanel(Constant.getTextBundle("การลงรหัส ICD-10"), aPanelDiagICD10);
    aPanelDiagIcd.addPanel(Constant.getTextBundle("การลงรหัส ICD-9"), aPanelDiagICD9);
```

I need to add `JSplitPane` between `JTabbedPane` and its component. The tabbed pane consists of 9 tabs. In that each tab consists of different functionality with different panel. But they added that the tabbed pane. How Can I set split pane between them, and what will be the left and right component for split pane?

```
splitPaneH= new javax.swing.JSplitPane();
splitPaneH.setOrientation(javax.swing.JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);

splitPaneH.setDividerLocation(0);
splitPaneH.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
splitPaneH.setLeftComponent( theJTabbedPane  );
//splitPaneH.setRightComponent( aSourceTabbedPane  );
```

Comment: I can't say I really understand the question, but..  Add the components to the split pane, then add the split pane to the tabbed pane.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't separate the tabs from their contents with another component like a `JSplitPane`.

However you can tell the `JTabbedPane` how and where you want your tabs to be layed out. Look at the constructors `JTabbedPane(int tabPlacement)` and `JTabbedPane(int tabPlacement, int tabLayoutPolicy)` (there are also setters/getters for these).

For tab placement use `JTabbedPane.LEFT`, or `JTabbedPane.RIGHT` and the result will be what you want to achieve.

If you have too many tabs, you can choose between `JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT` or `JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT`. The first will display all tabs in multiple rows/cols if needed, the latter one will only display as many that fits into the space and display scroll buttons to scroll to the not visible tabs.

**IF** you really want to separate tabs from their contents with something like a `JSplitPane`, you can't use `JTabbedPane` for this. You have to implement that yourself. E.g. put buttons (representing the tabs) on one side of a `JSplitPane`, and when those buttons are clicked, change the component on the other side of the `JSplitPane`.